# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append':Image processing example

Tags: python, image, numpy

I will first explain what I want to do. I have an image and I want to store the pixel values for a specific ROI. For that reason I implement the following loop(found in another topic of the site):

```
pixels = im.load() 

all_pixels = []
for x in range(SpecificWidth):
  for y in range(SpecificHeight):
    cpixel = pixels[x, y]
    all_pixels.append(cpixel)
```

However, it does not return a SpecificwidthXSpecificHeight matrix but one of length as much as the values. Because I want to keep the size of the matrix of the ROI I implement the following loop(much the same with the previous):

```
array=np.array(all_pixels)
roi_pixels = np.zeros((SpecificWidth,SpecificHeight))

for i in range(0,array.shape[0],width):
    c_roi_pixels=all_pixels[i]
    roi_pixels.append(c_roi_pixels)
```

And I have the error as it mentioned in the title.

Comment: To use vstack the arrays should have the same size and I am getting the error: ValueError all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RolandSmith is absolutely right about the cause of the error message you're seeing. A much more efficient way to achieve what you're trying to do is to convert the whole image to a numpy array, then use slice indexing to get the pixels corresponding to your ROI:

```
# convert the image to a numpy array
allpix = np.array(im)

# array of zeros to hold the ROI pixels
roipix = np.zeros_like(allpix)

# copy the ROI region using slice indexing
roipix[:SpecificHeight, :SpecificWidth] = allpix[:SpecificHeight, :SpecificWidth]
```

Comment: The syntax is `x[start:stop:step]` - you might want to take a look at [the documentation here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing)

Comment: I erase my comment because I read it before you answer. It works,thanks!

Comment: As I said, the syntax is `[start:stop:step]`. If you want the rows from 0 to 79, and the columns from 0 to 104 (in steps of 1), you could use `allpix[0:80:1, 0:105:1]`. There are *two* sets of slice indices in the square brackets, since you're indexing into two dimensions. Also remember that Python indexing starts at 0. Since the default start is 0 and the default step size is 1, you can just specify the stop indices for each dimension, i.e. `allpix[:80, :105]`.

Answer (score 4):

In numpy, `append` is a *function*, not a *method*.

So you should use e.g:

```
roi_pixels = np.append(roi_pixels, c_roi_pixels)
```

Note that the `append` function creates and returns a copy! It does not modify the original.

Comment: So the problem is due to the fact that I specify a zero matrix?

Comment: No. The problem is that `append` is not a *method* of the ndarray class.